# iphone tiling an image

Tags: iphone, tiles

I have an image which is 1280 x 1664 and I want to use the ScrollViewSuite example that Apple gives us but I need to cut this image up to multiple zoom levels.

So, does anybody know how I can tile an image at multiple zoom levels. There must be an easy way to tilling an image to 256x256 without cutting it by hand via photoshop?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Why do you want to "cut" the image?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

great find. I did a bit of researching from what you found and I've managed to add the row and col to the output filename. I've also resized the image to what percentage I want the image to be. So I can now do it all from 1 large image.

```
convert bigimage.png -resize 25% -crop 256x256 -set filename:tile "%[fx:page.x/256+1]_%[fx:page.y/256+1]" +repage +adjoin "tile_25_%[filename:tile].png"
```

Thanks a lot for helping me out, its saved me a lot of time. Hopefully I've helped you out?

Answer (score 4):

Funny -- I went to bed last night knowing this was the first thing I'd have to address this morning. I just found a remarkably simple solution to this. ImageMagick out of the box using convert with the -crop option:

`convert bigimage.png -crop 256x256 tile.png`

This makes as many tile files as necessary and most importantly creates rectangles on the right side and bottom..  all of the other solutions I explored made n,m evenly sized tiles out of the image.

The tiles are numbered tile-##.png where ## starts at zero. I'd have preferred -row#-col#.png, but this will work for me.  CATiledLayer, here I come.

Comment: Peter's solution that includes column and row information in the filenames is genius. I made a little shell script to rename the filenames, but this is so much more elegant. Works great. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

Jeff LaMarche rolled his own solution to this:

http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/10/cutting-large-images-into-tiles-for.html

There is also an app called Tilen available on the OS X App Store:

http://itunes.apple.com/jp/app/tilen/id409199185?mt=12

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the gdal2Tiles utility - which is particularly effective for generating map overlay tiles from a large input image.

Search for "gdal2tiles" here on StackOverflow, and also be sure to check out the Apple's TileMap sample code.  TileMap is available via the WWDC 2010 (free) download of samples.