# 3 small images over big image with resizing enabled for all? Iphone

Tags: iphone, image, uiscrollview, tiles

i have to make an offline map with icons but i will use images instead of maps because I don't know if there's any offline map code i can use available ?

Anyway, I wil use background image which is image of the map. Then I wanna add small ballon images over it. the Question is How can I apply scroll view or any code you know for applying maximize and minimize for all of them at the same time ??? or if you have a better idea can you please suggest it?

Thanks,
Dalal

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245351/iphone-tiling-an-image) for tiling images efficiently on an iOS device.

Also see the [Scrolling](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Scrolling/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008023) sample from Apple.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you'd have the balloons be subviews of the map's UIImageView, then subclass the UIImageView for the map and implement your own layoutSubviews method (layoutSubviews being a method of superclass UIView).  In that method you read the map view's size and resize/relocate the balloons accordingly.

Comment: Can you please explain more in how to use layoutSubviews because i'm not very familiar at XCODE language ???

Comment: Well, you'd need to be at least moderately familiar with Objective-C (or at least C/C++) and the basic UI API concepts to do this.  You subclass UIImageView similar to how you do it in C++ (though the syntax is different), and implement layoutSubviews.  Inside layoutSubviews you find the current size of yourself ("self") with "frame" (which returns a CGRect structure containing "origin" and "size"), then calculate from the size where and how large your balloons ("subviews") should be.  Resize/reposition them by setting their "frame" values.