# drawRect cropping in UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am trying to draw an image into a UIView subclass overriding drawRect. This image drawing class needs moving and zooming capabilities, so I made it a subview of a scrollview.

My problem is that my image seems to get cropped, either by the screen or the scrollView bounds (the image is larger than the screen). I don't have a clue why, this seems to e pretty basic stuff.

The view hierarchy in my ViewController looks like this:

```
View Controller
  View
    ScrollView
      MapView
```

I've created outlets for the scroll view and the map view (which is the view implementing drawRect).

My ViewController initial setup code for configuring the scroll view looks like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    scrollView.delegate = self; 
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(450, 476);
    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.6;
    scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 6.0;
}
```

My drawRect implementation:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{ 
    UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"map.jpg"];
    CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(0,0,450,476);
    [myImage drawInRect:rectangle];
}
```

The image is draggable and zoomable within the scroll view, but it's cropped at what seems to be the screen bounds.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

drawRect can't draw outside the rect passed as a parameter to the drawRect method, which is determined by the view frame. Make your view 1200,1200 and make sure that clipToBounds is disabled on all the containing views.

Comment: Ok so I'm guessing that's what the frame of my view does. Thank you for the information, that makes sense.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Set the view frame (actually it's the view.bounds, technically, but they're usually the same) and drawRect draws the contents of that frame.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably in `drawInRect`. From documentation of UIImage class:

```
drawInRect:
Draws the entire image in the specified rectangle, scaling it as needed to fit.
```

Make that rectangle bigger as you wish and center it in UIImageView. This question is answered here [UIScrollView image/photo viewer with paging enabled and zooming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975708/uiscrollview-image-photo-viewer-with-paging-enabled-and-zooming)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. But if i change the code to CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(0,0,1200,1200); it's still getting cropped. My rect dimensions in the posted code are the actual dimensions of the image.

Comment: Take a look at the link I posted above. There is sample code and WWDC video how to make whole photo application from apple. Search through for moving and zooming.

Comment: Ok, using your links I figured out I needed to set a frame for my mapView, using:
 
CGRect mapFrame; 
mapFrame.origin = CGPointMake(0, 0); 
mapFrame.size = CGSizeMake(450, 476); 
mapView.frame = mapFrame;