# While zooming in, UIScrollview calls scrollViewDidEndDecelerating - how to stop it?

Tags: ios, ios5, uiscrollview, scroll

When I zoom a photo in `UIScrollView` and push it down or up, the `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` method gets called. However, I don't want it until I scroll to the next image.

**How to stop it?**

For more info: I have one `UIScrollView` which includes 3 image view middle image view in another inner `UIScrollView`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to switch your UIScrollView to paging mode. See [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/ScrollViewPagingMode/ScrollViewPagingMode.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008179-CH3-SW1) for info. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975708/uiscrollview-image-photo-viewer-with-paging-enabled-and-zooming) too.

Comment: This is good resource links but next time please put some code snippets so user can get good understanding :)