# UIScrollView with dynamic text and image

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiscrollview

my application get news from a json address

and i have a image and text

my width textView is dynamic , maybe 100 character maybe 9000 character,
and i have a imageView in first of page

**i want to scroll all of page (text and image) !**

how i can create view to scroll all of them currectly ?

Comment: sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

there are lots of tutorials to help you do this. Depending on if you are using storyboards or not.

[UIScrollView image/photo viewer with paging enabled and zooming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975708/uiscrollview-image-photo-viewer-with-paging-enabled-and-zooming)

Basically, once you put your components on the storyboard. You write a class which is a scrollViewController.

You should load your image into a UIImageView, you can do this based on a URL

```
NSURL * imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.1.2x0/pic/LC.jpg"];
NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
UIImage * image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

Once you have a UIImage object you can resize it etc.

You will also need a json parser as well. Once you parse the data into some kind of datastructure you will be good to go :)

Comment: thanks man 
my problem actually is scroll dynamic text with image.character in each post is changeable,maybe 100 maybe 1000.and cant scroll all of page,

Answer (score 0):

If the data that you receive is unpredictable or very large, I recommend that you use UITableView instead of UIScrollView.

In UITableView, the cells are **re-used**. Thus, you don't have to worry about the memory related issues with UIScrollView.

Comment: And, if you want, I can post sample code as well. Just let me know.